# Flutter Certificate

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou tendo erro ao consulta uma api, por que está com erro no certificado queria saber se alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser já tentei varias maneiras e nada.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em português. Teria como editar a pergunta e colocar esse erro como texto? Incluir qual parte do código faz essa conexão também ajudaria a obter respostas mais facilmente.

Answer (score 0):

Passei por esse problema um dia desses!
Eu resolvi desta forma:

```
void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: 'home',
      routes: {
        'home': (BuildContext context) => Login(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}
```